# Clean Words for the Money?

Tags: translation, idiom-meaning, mistranslation

There is a discussion concerning how to translate the Norwegian expression ''Rene ord for Pengene" to English. The expression has the meaning that one has been quite forthright. Is it reasonable in this case to coin the neologism ''Clean Words for the Money'' by means of a literal translation.

Comment: Can you  please   add a usage example and context for the proverb?

Comment: Only if you have a reader-base as large and as sympathetic as that of say JK Rowling (and if you are as skilled a wordsmith as she is). English is _not_ D-I-Y.  'Calling a spade a spade' already exists in English and appears to have a similar meaning.

Comment: I have given an answer, but perhaps with a bit more context we can refine the answers below.

Comment: I was not allowed to delete the question. Let me just state, then, that some contributors here are utterly ridiculous and that it is totally unacceptable to state that the expression "Clean words for the money" is meaningless in English. Period!

Comment: Can you give more explanation of the Boreegian saying? It is not clear what it is supposed to mean. Like maybe a real life situation where one would say such a thing.

Comment: @Mitch The phrase "rene ord for pengene" is used when someone is being told severely and in no uncertain terms how things are. Sometimes the expression is used in opposition to what we call fog talk which serves to make things unclear.

Comment: “unvarnished reality”

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal To get the right nuance, can you invent a situation where the phrase is just right?  Who says this phrase to who? X says a fact Y to Z and Z says 'no, that's not true', and and X says your phrase to confirm truth? Or is X giving an order? 'no uncertain terms' is often associated with an order, telling someone to do something, somewhat confrontational.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I know  the meaning of the expression "no uncertain terms" and that is why I chose it. Typically if you give clean words for the money, "rene ord for pengene", you give an order or you give a reprimand. So if an officer in the army discovers some soldiers who have not cleaned their room they may get clean wirds for the money. I was just told that the expression was found in Danish already in the mid 1600s.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal 'In no uncertain terms' may well be the closest in meaning. It doesn't have the idiomaticity/poetry of the Norwegian, but it captures better the direction of what you want. The current answers all are about making a comment about something said, and voicing a possibly unpopular or unrecognized truth. But the Norwegian phrase seems to be about a command.

Comment: @Mitch One of my philosophy professors in California coined the expression "finding a philosophy job is as difficult as finding a fish in a tree". Is it meaningful? Of course, as is the phrase "Number three wanted to sleep".  Is the latter  understandable? That depends upon how it is used, and if e.g. the speaker with "number three" indicates one of several persons that may well be. Anyway, my point in all of this is to point out that ordinary languages are very flexible, and idioms come and go in inscrutable ways. So that is why the pot is calling the kettle black.

Comment: I suggest you ask your fimbul question here: linguistics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

I would probably translate it to:

> **Telling it like it is.**

This is an expression that means being upfront without any pretense.

It could also be translated to:

> **Offering my two cents.**

This means sharing my opinion in a plain manner.  I like this as a translation because it retains the sense of words for the money.

Answer (score 2):

> 'Calling a spade a spade' already exists in English and appears to have a similar meaning. – [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)

Comment: Norwegian also has "Kalle en spade en spade", and the meaning is not the same as "Rene ord for pengene".

Comment: I was not allowed to delete the question. Let me just state, then, that some contributors here are utterly ridiculous and that it is totally unacceptable to state that the expression "Clean words for the money" is meaningless in English. Period!

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal The thing is, it isn't an idiomatic phrase in English. Languages often have things that don't make literal sense in other languages. English has 'to have an axe to grind', for example, which is _grammatical_, but probably doesn't mean 'to want to have an argument' in Norwegian. Phrases of this type build meaning within their original languages, which don't necessarily work in others. See [English as she is spoke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke) for more proof that direct translations don't always work.

Comment: 'Clean words for the money' is ambiguous - is someone offering a word-cleaning service? Does someone sell 'clean words'? Is it an instruction, telling someone not to 'clean words for free'? These are all valid literal interpretations, which are a far cry from 'to be forthright'

Comment: An interesting example is with my compatriot he philosopher Arne Næss who wrote a didactic book in Critical Thinking. He probably read English literature where the term "straw man" was used for a fallacy. He translated directly and used "stråmann". The problem is that there are no strawmen in Norwegian, but there are scarebirds - or scarecrows.  So he should have translated "straw man" with "fugleskremsel", and the students would have gotten a feeling for the fallacy.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal: Exactly!